# Dynamic scope variable in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create dynamic scope variable in angular.I am using a loop to set the variable name as v1,v2,v3 but still no success.
Any idea how achieve this ?

js

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    $scope.v_i='value'+i;
  }
```

html

```
<div>{{v1}}</div>
<div>{{v2}}</div>
<div>{{v3}}</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you make it an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `$scope` object as typeof `Array`.
But I would wrap them to a `$scope` object wrapper `items`. 
See both approaches below.

**VIEW**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController">

  {{v0}}
  <br/> {{v1}}
  <br/> {{v2}}
  <br/> {{v3}}
  <br/>
  <br/> {{items}}
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item}}
  </div>


</div>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
 angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('MainController', MainController)

function MainController($scope) {
  $scope.items = {};  
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    $scope['v' + i] = 'value' + i;
    // or add to object wrapper
    $scope.items['v' + i] = 'value' + i;
  }
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/DaanDeSmedt/nhmwdujs/)

Comment: Given the HTML, looks like it would have to be `$scope['v' + i]`. Also, saying you're using it as  `Array` might be a bit misleading. You're using bracket notation on an object.

Comment: Sorry just remove the `_` on controller and view. But the approach is identical... As updated on above answer.

Comment: hi @daan.desmedt I'm having a similar issue and can you explain what `'value' + i` is supposed to do? I'm not sure the purpose of that line. Thank you!

Comment: Its just a way to set a scope variabele with the loop counter on a dynamic way. Not sure if this helps you?

Comment: @daan.desmedt  How do i use a dynamic scope variable inside the template to invoke the simillar dynamic variable already generated. For example i have dynamic variable scope.v +i  = 1122. Now i want to use a simillar dynamic variable inside the template with ng-repeat. Example {{v+$index}}  , for this i am getting v1  instead of 1122 in UI. Can you help me ?